# how to get j3d loader?

Tags: stl, java-3d

I'm doing a java 3D library regarding drawing different kind of shapes and generate them into an STL file. As I'm trying to code my STLFile class I found some import which I don't really understand. Can someone tell me where can I find the Loader or the library and how to use those import.

Below is the code that I found which I don't understand.

```
import com.sun.j3d.loaders.Scene;
import com.sun.j3d.loaders.SceneBase;
import com.sun.j3d.loaders.IncorrectFormatException;
import com.sun.j3d.loaders.ParsingErrorException;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.GeometryInfo;

. . .

public class STLFile implements Loader
{
. . .
}
```

There are more code but I 'm just showing the part which I not sure.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather look at [org.jogamp.java3d.loaders](https://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.7.0-final/javadoc/org/jogamp/java3d/loaders/package-frame.html) and [org.jogamp.java3d.utils.geometry](https://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.7.0-final/javadoc/org/jogamp/java3d/utils/geometry/package-frame.html). You can download Java 3D [here](https://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/). I advise you to read [my article](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/) to know how to get started with Java 3D.